# Volume of a set vs volume of its projections

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $V\subset\mathbb R^n$ be "nice" (measurable or Borel or open or convex...) and let $V_{\{i,j,...\}}$ be the projection of $V$ on the subspace spanned by $e_i,e_j,...$.

It is easy to see that $$\mu(V) \leq \prod_{i=1}^{i=n}\mu(V_{i})$$

What about projections on higher dimensional subspaces?
E.g., for $n=3$, is it true that

$$ \mu^2(V) \leq \mu(V_{12}) \mu(V_{13}) \mu(V_{23})$$

Comment: Before jumping to the Lebesgue measure, maybe start by asking the same question when $V$ is finite set and measures are replaced by cardinalities? I guess this should be easily settled.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loomis%E2%80%93Whitney_inequality

Comment: Also see IMO 1992 problem 5 (http://olivernash.org/2017/08/05/visualising-imo-results/index.html?1992-5).